# Implementing multiple level relationship (in Access)

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

My problem is about designing a table for a specific task, but as I'm new into databases I've become lost on the way.

So, I need to implement a table that contains some hour values, that contain some minute values that contains other specific data.

The (naive) approach that I have is something like this:

> **ParentTable**->  *1-to-M*  <-**ParentHours**->  *M-to-1*  <-**Hours**-> *M-to-1*  <-**HoursMinutes**->  *M-to-1*  <-**Minutes**->  *M-to-1*   <- **ChildTable**

...1-to-M stands for One-to-Many and the other way around. 
Hope it's readable by any means.

And my question is as follows. Is the way I have now any decent approach, or the task should be exploded into less relationship tables (if that's the case, any hints?)

I have to use MS Access, but I guess general idea is not constrained by specific platform.

Comment: That looks overly convoluted. Can you be more specific about what sort of data you want to store? Some examples would be best. -- Edit, thanks @Brian. :) Didn't look at the date. I assume the question isn't really current anymore...